# What is the subject of 'concerning' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the subject of 'concerning' in this sentence?

*by choosing the last of these alternatives my main subject has become the conceptions held by five of our major writers concerning the function and nature of literature*

Is it writers which are concerning or conceptions which are concerning?
After all what is his main subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per OED this is one of several cases in which a present participle has come to be used as a preposition, rendering moot the question of its subject:

> The present participle of *concern* (v. 2), used at length without reference to any subject, and retaining its verbal object: compare the series, ‘a matter intimately concerning your friend’, ‘he made to me a communication concerning your friend’, ‘I will communicate with you concerning your friend’, where concerning is, in the first the participle, in the third a preposition, in the second transitional, ‘your friend’ being its object in all.
>   Compare the similar use of regarding, touching: so modern French *concernant, touchant.* See also according to, during, notwithstanding, pending, in which prepositions, or prepositional phrases have in different ways arisen out of participles.